# WP7: camera capture sound while using 'PhotoCamera' class

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera, audio, image-capture

I'm using the PhotoCamera class to take a picture within my application. 
Is there a way to enable the capture sound present in the official camera application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can play it yourself as a SoundEffect when the picture is taken.

Free sound files as simple as camera shutter sounds can be found all over the Internet!

Comment: well I know that I can play it, but I was wondering if there's any official comment on this